# Where to set credit card details returned from the payment gateway

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I have made my custom redirect based payment method.

```
public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()
{
    return Mage::getUrl('pay/index/redirect', array('_secure' => true));
}
```

In the redirect action I am redirecting to the gateway url.

```
public function redirectAction() {
    $this->_redirectUrl("https://mygateway_url?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2);
}
```

It is returning the status of payment with the credit card details of the user.My question is that where to set the credit card details returned from the gateway service.

Answer (score 0):

It is depend on payment Gateway, Most payment Gateway dont give card detail if your site is not using https, For card detail you need to contact payment gateway support.